# Error CS0411 - EF 6, DotNet core 6, Ms SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

My scenario
Visual Studio 2022, Blazor WebApplication + ASPnet hosted (so 3 projects in my solution), SQL Server with existing DB (used by other apps).

TabUser has a FK with TabUserRoles (1 -> many)

so i try to scaffold db to create models for my entities. I use CMD with command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "connectionstring" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

everything works fine but... when I compile i receive a couple of **CS0411** errors for my tables

```
  entity.HasOne()   //entity is TabUserRoles
      .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdUser)
        HasConstraintName("Fk_UserRole_Users");
```

I can fix them by writing an explicit type

```
  entity.HasOne<TabUserRole>()                //<====== another Table/DBSet
      .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdUser)
        HasConstraintName("Fk_UserRole_Users");
```

this compiles successfully but when I try to retrieve data from TabUsers with

```
_context.TabUsers.ToList();  //error happens HERE
```

Error 500 from my Blazor server, developer tools console is

```
1 .Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

2. api/user:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[CAPhotoManager.Shared.ServiceResponse`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[CAPhotoManager.Shared.Model.TabUser, CAPhotoManager.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], CAPhotoManager.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at CAPhotoManager.Client.Services.UserService.GetUsers() in C:\Progetti\net\CAPhotoManager\CAPhotoManager\Client\Services\UserService.cs:line 17
   at CAPhotoManager.Client.Pages.Users.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Progetti\net\CAPhotoManager\CAPhotoManager\Client\Pages\Users.razor:line 25
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your connection string is correct?

Comment: I've copied from VS server explorer (of course setting password)

It's set on AppSettings and in Program.cs

builder.Services.AddDbContext<CAShootsContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
    );

Comment: OK, now look for the *real* error (server-side). The 500 is just telling you your code doesn't run, not why. I don't know how that works in Blazor, but I do know there's always a way.

Comment: OOOK, Error is NOT on "my" tables but in others.. 

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot use table 'Tab_UtentiRuolo' 
for entity type 'TabUtentiRuolo (Dictionary<string, object>)' 
since it is being used for entity type 'TabUtentiRuolo' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. 
Add a foreign key to 'TabUtentiRuolo (Dictionary<string, object>)' on the 
primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'Tab_UtentiRuolo'.'

but WTF I've NEVER changed anything (except for to fix the errors)